# Ruby on Rails polymorphic association - case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

How would you represent the following case in terms of Ruby-on-Rails associations?

> Content (name, description, link)

has one/belongs to one or more

> Author

which is one of these three types:

> Person (first_name, surname) OR Artist (artist_name) OR Duo (name1,
>   name2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was learning about polymorphic-associations there where 2 sources that really help me

1. [guides.rubyonrails.org polymorphic-associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)
2. [railscasts 1polymorphic-association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association)

you have to remember that you have a model that will connect with others so you need to have a **key value** to know to what model and row to connect

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contents, as: :commentable
end

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contents, as: :commentable
end
```

note that in your **Content** model you should add 
commentable_id (as a integer  key of the field you are connection to)

commentable_type (as a string, this is going to be the model name that you are connecting to)

```
Content (name, description, link, commentable_id, commentable_type)
```